# Create date from one year with string and int error - PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following problem. I want to create a date from another. To do this, I extract the year from the database date and then create the chosen date (day = 30 and month = 9) being the year extracted from the database.

The code is the following

```
bbdd20Q3['year']=(pd.DatetimeIndex(bbdd20Q3['datedaymonthyear']).year)
y=(bbdd20Q3['year'])
m=int(9)
d=int(30)
bbdd20Q3['mydate']=dt.datetime(y,m,d)
```

But error message is this

```
"cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>"
```

Comment: use: `bbdd20Q3['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime(bbdd20Q3['year'].astype(str) + '0930')`

Answer (score 0):

I think dt mean datetime, so the line 'dt.datetime(y,m,d)' create **datetime object type.**

bbdd20Q3['mydate'] should get int?
If so, try to think of another way to store the date (8 numbers maybe).

hope I helped :)

Comment: how does this answer the question? to me, this should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you did `import datetime as dt` then by doing:

```
bbdd20Q3['year']=(pd.DatetimeIndex(bbdd20Q3['datedaymonthyear']).year)
y=(bbdd20Q3['year'])
m=int(9)
d=int(30)
bbdd20Q3['mydate']=dt.datetime(y,m,d)
```

You are delivering series as first argument to `datetime.datetime`, when it excepts `int` or something which can be converted to `int`. You should create one datetime.datetime for each element of series not single datetime.datetime, consider following example

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"year":[2001,2002,2003]})
df["day"] = df["year"].apply(lambda x:datetime.datetime(x,9,30))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   year        day
0  2001 2001-09-30
1  2002 2002-09-30
2  2003 2003-09-30
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code with the required logic -

```
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'date': ['2019-12-14', '2020-12-15']})
print(df.dtypes)
# convert the date in string format to datetime object, 
# if the date column(Series) is already a datetime object then this is not required
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print(f'after conversion \n {df.dtypes}')
# logic to create a new data column
df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime({'year':df['date'].dt.year,'month':9,'day':30})
```

@eollon I see that you are also new to Stack Overflow. It would be better if you can add a simple sample code, which others can tryout independently
(keeping the comment here since I don't have permission to comment :) )